# Unregister token on new Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the new google cloud messaging as below link : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

I want to unregister device. I use this code but token still active. It doesn't work

```
String authorizedEntity = MY_PROJECT_SENDER_ID;
String scope = "GCM";
InstanceID.getInstance(context).deleteToken(authorizedEntity,scope);
```

So how to unregister device with new Gcm ? It is possible ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription), it would take a while before the token becomes inactive after unregistration.